# Changing Discord's (and maybe other app's) accent color

Tags: color

So in Linux, the Discord's accent color is actually violet (or purple) but on Windows its "blurple", is there anyway to get that accent color back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux is customizable, so https://plusinsta.github.io/discord-plus/ download any theme and edit it. There is a lot of themes for discord. It is time to learn how to customize.

One more search in Google: https://github.com/xCuri0/discordcolor

By the way this is Elementary OS forum. Discord is not a part of any Linux distro.